# Angular mat-tab go back to first tab from another class

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-tab

I am using `mat-tab-group` to create two tabs which then link to other components:

```
            <mat-tab-group>
                <mat-tab label="Notifications">
                    <app-notification-rules-container>
                    </app-notification-rules-container>
                </mat-tab>
                <mat-tab label="Create New">
                     <app-notification-account>
                     </app-notification-account>
                </mat-tab>
            </mat-tab-group>
```

On the `app-notification-account` component I have a cancel button and when that is clicked I want to go back to the first tab. How do I navigate back to the first tab from a different component class?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use @Output in your child component. it helps when you want to transfer data from child component to parent.
so let say in app-notification you are handling a cross button, so when this button is clicked, emit an event, which will be listened to by the parent (where mat-tab-group) is used, and in mat-tab-group, you can use the selectedIndex property to change the selected tab.

https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs

So in-app-notification-account.ts

```
...
 constructor() {
   @Output() changeTab = new EventEmitter<();
   // this will emit event , which will be listened by parent
   handleCancel(){
    this.changeTab.emit(true)
  }
}
```

in your parent component, where the mat tab is being used
in .html

```
<mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="selectedIndex">
<mat-tab label="Notifications">
                    <app-notification-account (changeTab)="changeTab()">
                    </app-notification-account>
                </mat-tab>
    </mat-tab-group>

in .component.ts 
.. changeTab() {
   this.selectedIndex = this.selectedIndex === 1 ?0:1
  // or if you always want to go to first tab just set selectedIndex = 0
}
```

Comment: The tab still changing back to the first one. I can see `changeTab()` is getting called when I click on the cancel button but it is not going back to the first tab. I tried putting `this.selectedIndex = 0;` into the `changeTab()` function but it's not working

Comment: have you intiated selctedIndex with 0 in main component and added that selectedIndex in mat-tab-group?

Comment: selectedIndex = 0 , will make first tab as active tab you will have to use output in the component where your cancel butoon is

Comment: Yes I have added selctedIndex to the main component and the mat-tab-group

Comment: use @output in the component , where you want cancel button functionality

Comment: can you make a stackbliz demo? for this?

Comment: I got it working now. Also had to add `selectedIndexChange` to mat-tab-group